# Angular - css style changes in the list of objects in *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I have two components, parent:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="itemList != null">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
    <component-item [componentItem]="item"></component-item>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

and child (component-item):

```
<div class="row myClass" [ngClass]="{'selected': isSelected }" (click)="method()">
    ...
</div>
```

As a result I have list of items. I have two css styles: default and "selected". I would like to change styles of items after clicking on them like: when I click on the first item it should change to "selected" and then after clicking second item it should change to "selected" and the first one return to the default. My variable "isSelected" is a boolean type and I change its value on "true" in "method()". How can I change its value on "false" when I select another item from the list?

Comment: Can you show how `isSelected` is getting updated - the HTML and the event handler

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this, it may work
```

In component.ts File
    cssEnabled:any="";

```
private method(itemName:string)
{

 this.cssEnabled=itemName;

}
In compontent.html :

<div class="row myClass" [ngClass]="{'selected': componentItem==cssEnabled}" (click)="method(componentItem)">
    ...
</div>
```